# Problem with multibranch pipeline jobs with branches that have a slash in their name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

There has been many stackoverflow questions about various issues related to multibranch pipeline with slash in their branch name.  I have even created a Jenkins [JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57324) for my specific situation (latest Jenkins + plugins and config file provider plugin).  However  I would like to get some clarification.  I tried looking at the source code but I got lost because the pipeline plugin used to be called the workflow plugin and now the source code project is called workflow-aggregator (I think) but when I look at this plugin I cannot understand how it relates/include the other plugins in the list of plugins.  Here are my observations(I am on Windows if that matters):

1. It used to be that Jenkins would use the three characters %2F in folder names in place of / in branches.
2. Then this was changed to _ instead of %2F
3. Now it is back to %2F (with all latest plugins)

So here are my questions:

1. Is there somewhere documented why %2F was re-instated?
2. Could someone point me to which plugin and what version last used _ instead of %2F as this is causing me grief and I would like to work around this?
3. Is there some code I could put to configure this behaviour with the existing latest plugins?  I saw this [post](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226122247-How-to-Customize-Checkout-for-Pipeline-Multibranch-) but it does not provide me with an example for declarative pipelines and with SVN as the SCM.  The issue with declarative pipelines is that the code in this post requires you to disable the declarative SCM checkout step (using the skipDefaultCheckout() option) and I do not know how to configure the branch folder path name.  I do not want the remote URL to be specified in the Jenkins file but rather in the Jenkins job configuration.

Any help is truly appreciated

Comment: I have same question, Mario. Perhaps we should ask this on the jenkins users Google Group. Or maybe even better, the Jenkins Developers Google Group. My initial search there for "slash in multibranch pipeline" has zero hits however. :-( https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!forum/jenkinsci-users https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!forum/jenkinsci-dev

Comment: Also, I assume you followed the long dev thread about this? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34564?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer for your 3rd question.

> Is there some code I could put to configure this behaviour with the existing latest plugins?

The idea is to, get the `BRANCH_NAME` built in variable, and replace everything that is not an alphanumeric character.
Later, use this folder instead of the default workspace.

In the Jenkins file:

```
buildFolder = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(BRANCH_NAME, "UTF-8");

// Replace nasty chars
buildFolder = buildFolder.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "_");

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'my_project'
            customWorkspace "W:\\workdir\\${buildFolder}"
            // or customWorkspace "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/${buildFolder}"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the built-in `JOB_NAME` variable to fix the generated workspace path by replacing all the encoded slashes (`%2F`) with their original form. `JOB_NAME` variable (for multi-branch jobs) contains an encoded branch name and can be used to generate a valid workspace path:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            customWorkspace URLDecoder.decode("workspace/$JOB_NAME")
            // other node options (eg. label, kubernetes, docker, dockerfile, etc)
        }
    }
}
```

This way we ensure the workspace is unique for each project (compared to the [original suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74519097/2443502)) to avoid overlapping workspace directories in case the same `BRANCH_NAME` value is used for different projects.

The path used in the solution is relative to the workspace root of the node ([docs](https://shorturl.at/uMVX8))

> It can be either a relative path, in which case the custom workspace will be under the workspace root on the node