# Jenkins multibranch pipeline builds fail for branch names with slashes

Tags: jenkins, nuget

I have a Jenkins job that uses Git Plugin Multibranch Pipelines.  The problem I have deals with branches containing slashes.

*Example*:
branch name is `feature/PROJECT-123-add-feature-x`

Jenkins creates the workspace folder by replacing `/` with `%2F`.

E.g. `F:\j\workspace\project\reponame\feature%2FPROJECT-123-add-feature-x`

Then the job runs "nuget pack", which fails with:
`CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'F:\j\workspace\project\reponame\feature\project-123-add-feature-x\packages\Lib.1.1.0\lib\net45\Lib.dll' could not be found [F:\j\workspace\project\reponame\feature%2FFSLTDK-123-add-feature-x\project_name.csproj]`

**Notice how nuget converts the `%2F` in the pathname to a `\` (backslash).**

This does not appear to be a Jenkins issue, because if I create a folder name like `C:\Temp\X%2F` and run `nuget pack` on a project in this folder, e.g., I get errors due to the `%2F` being converted to a `\` by nuget.

***Questions***:

1. Can I configure the Git plugin to convert the `/` character in the branch name to
   something other than `%2F`?  E.g. `-`?
2. Can I prevent users from
   creating the branch name with a `/` in it?  Jira is often used to
   create the branch name and defaults to creating branch names like
   `bugfix/xyz`, `release/xyz`, etc.
3. Any other ideas to workaround this?

Comment: have you considered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70094144/percent-in-folder-name-generated-by-jenkins-but-not-supported-by-visual-studio ?

Comment: Thanks!  That looks like a valid workaround.  Not sure how I missed that post.